# How to recover lost alias of keystore file?

Tags: android, alias, keystore

I know the answer might be impossible. But I still hope.

I have a **keystore** file and **another copy version**.

Then I add a **new alias** to **keystore** file and release new app with the new created **alias**.

Problem is: **I lost the keystore file**. All I have now is the copy version of keystore (it doesn't contain the new created alias).
I know the name and password of the alias. Is there any chance to take it back?

Comment: You created a new alias to an existing key or did you also generate a new key?

Comment: @Henry I create a new alias to an existing keystore file. Then I lost that keystore file. Now I have only the copy version of original keystore, which doesn't contain the alias I created.

Comment: Ok, just checked the documentation, it seems that keytool does not allow one key to have two alias names. In that case you lost the key. There is no way to get it back unless you can recover the original keystore file.

Answer (score 7):

To recover/see full content inside keystore with the command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore <name of keystore file>
```

To do this, you will need to provide the keystore password (not the alias password).

Comment: No sir, please read carefully my question. I already know that the alias is not in my current keystore file. I have only the copy of original keystore, which doesn't contains the new created alias.

Comment: @TOP ups I'm so sorry... Then... In my opinion...You can't do it bro...but i'm not really sure.

Comment: I know it might be impossible. Btw, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple to do retrieve the alias name:
`keytool -list -keystore <name of keystore file>`
This will Appear

```
    Enter keystore password:                                                                    
    Keystore type: jks                                                                          
    Keystore provider: SUN                                                                      

    Your keystore contains 1 entry                                                              

    aliasname, Aug 2, 2018, PrivateKeyEntry,                                                
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change alias of keystore file that you make an copy with:

```
keytool -changealias -keystore MY_KEYSTORE_2.jks -alias XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX -destalias MY_ALIAS
```

Comment: Could you please describe more clearly? Or give me an example

Comment: example the first you have keystore a.jks (alias a_alias) and make an copy a_copy.jks but you changed alias to (a_copy_alias). You lost a.jks file. You can use keytool -changealias -keystore a_copy.jks -alias a_copy_alias -destalias a_alias to recover to a.jks.

Comment: The problem is I made a copy before creating the alias. So  the a_copy.jks doesn't contain the alias that I created

Comment: Could you use keytool -list -v -keystore a_copy.jks to show alias that this file display ? If it empty pls remove -alias a_copy_alias in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Each alias corresponds to a unique key in the keystore file. Unfortunately, there is no way to restore the second key from the lost keystore file since the copy knows nothing about it.